# Adjust size Datagridview and print

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

my code is supposed to print a datagridview.
I could print, but the only problem is that is printing only one part of the dgv, like it is too small the dgv. I think I need to make it to rescale automatically. Do you guys know what it is the problem?
PS: The datagridview size is going to be different every time somebody uses it, it depends how many products the user add on it.

My code to print is this one

```
Private Sub BtnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        Dim PrintDialog1 As New PrintDialog()
        PrintDialog1.Document = PrintDocument1
        Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
            PrintDocument1.Print()
        End If
        PrintDocument1.Print()
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
        Dim bm As New Bitmap(Me.gridDoces.Width, Me.gridDoces.Height)
        gridDoces.DrawToBitmap(bm, New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.gridDoces.Width, Me.gridDoces.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, New Rectangle(500, 500, 500, 500))
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Printing a DGV as a flatten image is not a good practice. You must print every row with DrawString.
Take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj okaay! I am going to take a look, Thanks..

Comment: Because you are going to struggle with measurements if your grid is more of one page ( > 297 mm)